# Two seemingly equivalent definitions; one compiles, the other doesn't

Tags: haskell

This code:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
liftIOToApp = lift
```

Gives this error:

```
No instance for (MonadTrans t0) arising from a use of `lift'
In the expression: lift
In an equation for `liftIOToApp': liftIOToApp = lift
```

But after adding an argument to both sides, it compiles fine:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans
liftIOToApp a = lift a
```

These two definitions of `liftIOToApp` seem equivalent to me. Please explain.

Comment: Probably the monomorphism restriction.  Are you in GHCi or GHC?  The rules are a bit different for GHCi so the type checker isn't supposed to get in the way as much making interactive development easier.

Comment: If you try giving it an explicit type signature, you might win.

Comment: @bheklilr This was in GHC. Monomorphism restriction will be the cause then. Thanks